# How to find SubscriberKey in Mobile Connect Data views

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have sent adoc sms via mobile connect to Service Cloud Contact. we want to sync the record back to service cloud.
We have checked Below data views but unable to find SubscriberKey
1)_smsmessagetracking
2)_MobileAddress

Please let us know which data view has subscriberKey(Salesforce ContactId) or what is the best way to sync records to Service Cloud

Note- We don't have unique Mobile number in service cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since _subscribersms doesn't available in Mobileconnect, so not able to combine it with _smsmessagetracking.

I have done a workaround by combining _MobileAddress and _smsmessagetracking to get SFDC 18 digit ContactId known as subscriber key in SFMC and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If these subscribers also exist on the email channel (All Subs list) you can join `subscriberid` from the smsmessagetracking data view to the _subscriber data view to get `subscriberkey`

Answer (score -1):

You should combine Dataviews _smsmessagetracking and _subscribersms and create a relationship based on Mobile & MobileNumber or on SubscriberId.

You should be able to retrieve the SubscriberKey like this.

Comment: the _subscribersms data view is only from SMSi and not mobile connect  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribersms.htm&type=5